# VIM: `[y`] lost last character?

Tags: vim

I met the problem in VIM that `` `[y`] `` yanked the text between `` `[ `` and `` `] `` but lost the last character.

To reproduce:

1. put the cursor on some word in normal mode.
2. press `yiw`
3. run `:echom @@` to see the word is yanked correctly
4. press `` `[ `` and `` `] `` to see the marked positions, normally `` `[ `` is at the start of the word, `` `] `` is at the end of the word.
5. press `` `[y`] ``
6. run `:echom @@` again. This time the word is yanked but last character lost.

Any ideas about this? Thanks :)

(VIM version: 7.4 and 8.1)

(Gnome Terminal and tmux tested on Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04)

Comment: Not reproducible with vim 8.1

Comment: Really? I just updated my vim to version 8.1, but still found the problem existed. @wurtel

Comment: @wurtel It's possible you didn't reproduce it because you used `yw` (which will place the <code>\`[</code> mark at the start of the next work) instead of `yiw` (which will place it at the end of the current one.) See my answer for more details.

Comment: @PorcupineAndrew You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Comment: @filbranden I misread, I did `y1w`. I need to increase the font size on my browser :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually expected. TL;DR: Use `` `[v`]y `` instead.

The `` `[ `` motion is exclusive. See [`:help mark-motions`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#mark-motions), which says:

> With `` ` `` (backtick): The cursor is positioned at the specified location and the motion is [exclusive](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#exclusive).

Using visual mode instead, with `` `[v`]y ``, will typically work. It is actually controlled by the [`'selection'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27selection%27) option, but that defaults to "inclusive", so it's typically fine. (And if you want to make sure, you can temporarily reset it inside a function.)

See an example in Vim's manual under [`:help g@`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#g%40), which uses:

> ```
> function! CountSpaces(type, ...)
>   let sel_save = &selection
>   let &selection = "inclusive"
>   ...
>   silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
>   ...
>   let &selection = sel_save
> endfunction
> ```

Also, [this section](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/33.html#copying-the-text) from Learn Vimscript the Hard Way, which briefly touches on the subject. (More importantly, it uses the same idiom. You'll also find this same idiom in many Vim plug-ins.)

Comment: Thanks for you help! Pitifully I couldn't vote for your answer for now due to my poor reputation. Actually this question was raised just after I read _Learn Vimscript the Hard Way_, one chapter after what you mentioned, where the author changed `` `[v`]y `` to `` `[y`] `` but didn't mention this feature, so I was confused. I should have checked manual first.

Comment: @PorcupineAndrew Glad this helped! It wasn't that easy finding the right part of the manual that explains this behavior, so don't worry. Cheers!